# When I try to pose my rig, the mesh won't move correctly

Tags: mesh, rigging, bones, distort

I've already made sure the weight painting is all correct, but it **still** won't move along the rig the way it needs to.
[image: The bones, not lined up correctlywith the mesh]

[image]

Comment: Hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @moonboots Thanks, added it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two bones that affect same vertices of your mesh. Just fix weights and rig will work like you expect
[image]

[image]

Comment: That worked, but now when I try and move the top leg bone, it moves on its own like it's not parented to the spine anymore. Same with the shoes, they just disconnect

Comment: Ok, thank you both so much! It's pretty much all fixed now.    =D

Answer (score 0):

The direction of your leg bones is not correct, select them and <kbd>RMB</kbd> > *Switch Direction*, then parent each foot to each calf:

[image]

Maybe join all the other objects to the body? Then parent again *With Automatic Weights*, the arms will work fine.